# I can not match group in ssh using RSA Key with passphrase

Tags: ssh, linux-mint, openssh, rsa

I have two accounts on my computer. One account is named bob. The other account is for a user named joe. I am using RSA key with a passphrase. I can connect BUT when I add the lines Match Group joe and restart ssh I get a connection refused error. Everything else I do seems to work.

```
ChrootDirectory /home/joe
ForceCommand internal-sftp
AllowTcpForwarding no
```

until I add:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match Group joe
ChrootDirectory /home/joe
ForceCommand internal-sftp
AllowTcpForwarding no
```

I took the public key out of joe account to see if that would help but nothing I do seems to jail the joe account. I would love any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the user `joe` in the group `joe`?  You could try:

```
Match User joe
```

You need to restart sshd after any change.  The directory /home/joe must belong to joe and have permissions set appropriately too. Also, I recall reading somewhere that it's better to create a new directory to jail the user rather than using an existing `/home`

Comment: thank you for your help yes joe and joe user where in the same group. I think there where some errors in my config file I used about back up and got it working.